# Given that $\pi$ is not the zero of a nonzero polynomial with rational coefficients, prove that $\pi^2$ cannot be written in the form $a \pi + b$,

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given that $\pi$ is not the zero of a nonzero polynomial with rational coefficients, prove that $\pi^2$ cannot be written in the form $a \pi + b$,
where $a$ and $b$ are rational.

I'm not sure how to go about this.  If I suppose $\pi^2 = a \pi + b$ then $b = \pi^2 - a\pi$, and if $a = \frac {p}{q}$, then $\pi(q\pi - p) = bq$, which doesn't seem to be a true relation.  But the mention of it not being a zero is what confuses me.

Comment: If $ \pi^2 = a \pi + b $, what can you say about the roots of the polynomial $ x^2 - ax - b $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that there exists $(a,b)\in \mathbb Q^2$ such that $$\pi^2=a\pi+b.$$

Then

$$\pi^2-a\pi-b=0$$

so the polynomial

$$X^2-aX-b$$

as a root : $\pi$.

Which is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it can be written as $ π^2 = aπ + b$

π will become zero of $x^2 -a.x - b$.

But since it is given that $π$ is not zero of a polynomial, our assumption is wrong.